# Java compiler shows error that "integer is too large"

Tags: java, compiler-errors, integer

I am writing a code in which I am trying to assign a value in long variable.
But java compiler is showing error that too large integer number.
I am trying to store `600851475143` in `long` type still.

```
class Sum {
    static public void main(String args[]){
        long num=600851475143;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is standard practice to put `public` before `static`: `public static void main(...)`

Comment: When asking questions, remember to also post the *real [compiler] error message* and, better, *search for the error* before asking a question ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757763/integer-number-too-large-error-message-for-600851475143 ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924896/java-long-number-too-large-error - from `[java] integer too large` search ..

Comment: I wll take care of it... Thank you,assylias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l;
>   otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit 1.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So use this -

```
long num=600851475143l;
```

or better

```
long num=600851475143L;
```

Comment: I prefer a capital `L`, because `l` looks to similar to `1`.

Comment: Actually it is recommended. :)

Comment: I know. Wrote the comment long before you mentioned it in the answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

append 'L' or 'l' at the end of the number to make it a long literal.you can use both lowercase(l)or uppercase(L), but uppercase(L) is recommend for readability.

```
 long num=600851475143L;
```