# epoch time stamp , find number of days

Tags: java

i am trying to find number of days from todays date from the below epoch timestamp:-

> 1560593315387

like this :

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1558353632),Instant.now()));
```

It is working fine for 1558353632 but for 1560593315387 it cannot convert and not giving expected results.

Answer (score 2):

`1560593315387` looks to be milliseconds, not seconds, so use `Instant.ofEpochMilli`.

It is also too long (hah!) to fit into an `int`, so you have to use a `long` literal instead ([with an `L` at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757777/14955)).

```
 ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1560593315387L), Instant.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do

```
    int seconds = (int) 1560593315387l / 1000;// (millisecond to senconds conversion)

    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds), Instant.now()));
```

Comment: not working . it is showing error .. integet too long

Comment: please check now

Comment: _"integet too long"_ Just use `long` instead of `int`.